# how to convert dictionary of list to pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have this dictionary with list of items, but i'm having issues converting it to a pandas dataframe, this is a response i get on hitting an endpoint

```
{'monologues': [{'speaker': 0,
   'elements': [{'type': 'text',
     'value': 'So',
     'ts': 0.0,
     'end_ts': 0.18,
     'confidence': 0.93},
    {'type': 'punct', 'value': ' '},
    {'type': 'text',
     'value': 'this',
     'ts': 0.18,
     'end_ts': 0.36,
     'confidence': 1.0},
    {'type': 'punct', 'value': ' '},
    {'type': 'text',
     'value': 'is',
     'ts': 0.36,
     'end_ts': 0.42,
     'confidence': 1.0},
    {'type': 'punct', 'value': '.'}]}]}
```

i want to get ts, end_ts and value into a dataframe

expected dataframe is:

```
    Words   ts      end_ts
0   so      0.0     0.18
1   this    0.18    0.36
```

This is what i have tried but not giving me the actual response i expected

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(transcript_json, columns=transcript_json.keys())
df.head()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the dict then append it to a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

js = {'monologues': [{'speaker': 0,
   'elements': [{'type': 'text',
     'value': 'So',
     'ts': 0.0,
     'end_ts': 0.18,
     'confidence': 0.93},
    {'type': 'punct', 'value': ' '},
    {'type': 'text',
     'value': 'this',
     'ts': 0.18,
     'end_ts': 0.36,
     'confidence': 1.0},
    {'type': 'punct', 'value': ' '},
    {'type': 'text',
     'value': 'is',
     'ts': 0.36,
     'end_ts': 0.42,
     'confidence': 1.0},
    {'type': 'punct', 'value': '.'}]}]}

inner_js = [val for _, val in js.items()][0][0]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Words', 'ts', 'end_ts'])
for i in inner_js['elements']:
    if i.get('ts') or i.get('end_ts'):
        df = df.append({'Words':i['value'], 'ts':i['ts'], 'end_ts':i['end_ts']}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm grateful @DGS